# Async or sync replication at indexing in Azure search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'd like to know how multiple replicas replicated asynchronously or synchronously in Azure Search. 
If it's master-slave architectures, how slaves are replicated with master when the master get updated?

Comment: You need to add more details in your question.

Comment: I added more description. If it's master-slave architectures, how slaves are replicated with master when the master get updated?

Comment: Let me ask one more question: what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is whether replicas are ready and available right after scale operation completes in Azure Portal then the answer is no.

Once the scale operation completes from management perspective there is still some time needed for new replicas to get provisioned and sync data. How long does that take depends on the number of replicas, and amount of data your search service has.

Scale blade will display status 'Updating' when scaling operation is still in progress though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!  Actually my question is that If it's master-slave architectures, how slaves are replicated with master when the master get updated? (Sorry for my poor explanation).  looks like it's async. Correct?

Comment: Let me ask one more question: what problem are you trying to solve?